Kid kills his family after they moved into a haunted house
As a kid I remember watching this movie with my dad and I believe it was inspired on a true story(maybe not). So the movie is about how this family moved into this house that was possessed by a demon or the devil. In this movie the a teenage boy is being possessed by this demon and grabs a gun that was hanging on the wall and I believe kills his mom and dad, don't remember if he killed his sister. I also remember that he was arrested and in jail he kept speaking to the devil or acting like it. 
I think he got an attorney that tried to act like it was a mental disorder. This movie from what I remember seemed like it was from the 80's or 90's. No this movie isn't sinister or any modern/recent films. A few other scenes I remember was that the dad was in a craw space I think and there were a bunch of cockroaches. Along with that I think the water was be incredibly dark. I remember the dad wanted to stay but the wife really felt something was off.

Amityville II: The Possession (1982)

A family moves into their new home, which proves to be evil, resulting
  in the demonic possession of the teenage son.
Then strange things begin to happen: the mirror in the kitchen falls
  when they say grace, objects move by themselves, the faucet runs blood
  instead of water. The mother believes the house is evil and asks the
  local priest to come and bless it. 
......
  Later that night, the evil spirit tells Sonny to "kill 'em" to which he goes and gets his father's gun, shoots his father, then his mother,
  his younger sister, his younger brother, and after a chase finally
  kills Patricia.
The next day the police have arrived and pick up the bodies; Sonny is arrested, but states he does not recall of ever killing his family,
  and is taken away. Father Adamsky then realizes that Sonny is
  possessed and asks the church if he can perform an exorcism on Sonny
  but they refuse, not believing him. He therefore takes it upon himself
  to free Sonny, and frees him from the prison and takes him to church
  where Sonny escapes after seeing the crosses on the doors.
  ....


Yes that was the movie, thank you so much.

You're welcome :)
